# How to install "memcached" to php 5.6?

Tags: centos6, memcached, php-memcached

I had installed PHP 5.6.20 from this source. https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

But I cannot install memcached. Just only memcache.
How to install memcache**d** to PHP 5.6?

This is what i tried.

```
[root@testcentos ~]# yum -y install php56w-pecl-memcached.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror2.totbb.net
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: mirrors.nwsuaf.edu.cn
 * remi-safe: mirror.neolabs.kz
 * updates: mirror2.totbb.net
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:2.2.0-2.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-igbinary(x86-64) for package: php56w-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-2.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcachedutil.so.2()(64bit) for package: php56w-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-2.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.11()(64bit) for package: php56w-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-2.w6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmemcached10.x86_64 0:1.0.16-1.ius.el6 will be installed
---> Package php56w-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 0:1.2.1-2.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts libmemcached < 1.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: libmemcached10 conflicts with libmemcached-0.31-1.1.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Having webtatic + ius + remi configured on the same serveur can only raise issues. Example pulling php56w-pecl-igbinary from webtatic and libmemcached10 from IUS can be a source of problem. You should probably stick with a single provider for the PHP stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test first with

```
yum remove libmemcached-0.31-1.1.el6.x86_64
```

And then

```
yum install php56w-pecl-memcached.x86_64
```

Or just

```
yum install php56w-pecl-memcached
```

Greetings.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.
I'm not familiar with these command, thanks again.